# Laravel 5.7.17 file validation issue

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

The example is based on Laravel's registration.

I have added following to register.blade.php:

```php
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="file" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Files') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
```

The method in RegisterController looks like this:

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'files.*' => ['required', 'file'],
    ]);

    dd($validator->errors());
}
```

I'm trying to upload a PDF and a DOC file.:

```php
MessageBag {#236 ▼
  #messages: array:2 [▼
    "files.0" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The files.0 must be a file."
    ]
    "files.1" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "The files.1 must be a file."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Must be a file? These are files...

Comment: please post your form in the html file

Comment: I tested this on a fresh installation with the basic register form:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/stubs/make/views/auth/register.stub

Comment: You have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526273/4848587

Comment: You should check your php.ini too for ‍`upload_max_size` and `post_max_size`, if your file's size or sum of size of your files is bigger than those configs, php can not to upload them and laravel validation does not work properly

Answer (score 6):

just add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: The required validation does not apply if no file is selected. Pdf validation works`'files.*' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:pdf'],` Do you have any idea?

Comment: have you tried to validate the array alone `'files' => ['required'],` without removing `'files.*' => ['required', 'file']`?

Comment: also try to change `name="files[]" ` to `name="files" `

Comment: For multiple files **[]** is required

Comment: I tested `'files' => ['required', 'array']` and it worked, so please provide more details about the problem if it aint working

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'files.*' => ['required', 'mimes:doc,docx,pdf,txt'],
    ]);

    dd($validator->errors());
}
```